# How to install just mt.exe?

Tags: winapi, sdk, manifest, mt

The manifest tool `mt.exe` is included in the Windows SDK. But the full SDK is large and includes a lot of things as shown in the screenshot. But which of these options actually includes `mt.exe`?

Ideally I'd like to install just the minimum to get this tool on the system.

[image]

It does say [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/mt-exe) that mt "*is available in the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)*" - but thats it, without any further detail.

Comment: Also note that [Resource Hacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Hacker) will, among other things, properly install the manifest file in the executable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Choose **Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps**.

Additionally, you can then grab the mt.exe binary and put it in a location of your choice, if you don't want to keep the rest of the stuff that comes with that option (say, on a build server). The mt.exe doesn't have any dependencies other than OS dlls.

Answer (score 6):

If you have downloaded the ISO file of Windows SDK, grab the MSI called "**Windows SDK for Windows Store Apps Tools-x86_en-us.msi**" in the folder *Installers*

You can just extract (without installing) the content with an administrative installation:

```
msiexec /a "path_of_your_msi\Windows SDK for Windows Store Apps Tools-x86_en-us.msi" TARGETDIR="Full_Extract_Folder_Path" /qb
```

Then search mt.exe in your extract folder

Comment: I also had to copy midlrtmd.dll for mt.exe to run.